# Android app is not launching

Tags: android

i had a working application until i changed the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml. I changed it back, but then i found that i had two files in the gen folder.
I usually (as now) have sg like this:

[image]

But that time had something else in my gen folder: just "com.bfarago" as far as i remember and another R.java inside that was complaining about the package name. I deleted this package with the R.java and since then i cannot launch the application.
I exited and restarted eclipse and at the launch its stuck at this point:

```
[2011-02-12 14:04:55 - Nevnap] Android Launch!
[2011-02-12 14:04:55 - Nevnap] adb is running normally.
[2011-02-12 14:04:55 - Nevnap] Performing com.bfarago.nevnap.MainActivity activity launch
[2011-02-12 14:04:55 - Nevnap] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-02-12 14:04:55 - Nevnap] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-02-12 14:04:55 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting
[2011-02-12 14:04:59 - Nevnap] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-02-12 14:04:59 - Nevnap] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
```

Logcat:

```
02-12 14:06:21.795: WARN/MountService(65): Waiting too long for mReady!
```

Later i will need to recreate the whole app but now i want this to work again.

Please help me..

Comment: Have you already tried `Project` -> `Clean`?

Comment: package renaming in eclipse is always a bad idea and afaik it is buggy for some reason. but that is just what i heard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I am posting this to close the topic as i first commented this weeks ago)

Thank you guys. Luckily i had the .apk file on my phone so I just copied it to computer and now it's working again.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely delete any R.java and it will regenerate them for you. Try making a new AVD and restarting your computer to fix the second problem .

Comment: Thank you guys. Luckily i had the .apk file on my phone so I just copied it to computer and now it's working again.